# Initializer list and range-based function

Tags: c++, vector, c++11, iostream, initializer-list

Problem:
Write a program that prompts the user to enter some number of 1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50 and 100 dollar bills. Query the user separately for the number of each size dollar.

I think I've completed the code pretty well but the last part of the question states:
Modify your program to use an initializer list for the vector, and use a range-based for statement to traverse the vector. Note: These C++11 features are available in g++-4.6 and Visual Studio 2012, but may not be available on other compilers.

I don't understand what the last part is asking. Hopefully someone here can point me in the right direction. This is a C++ class and my book doesn't have the newest version.

Any critique on my code format would also be great!

Here is my code:

```
 #include "std_lib_facilities_3.h"
    vector<int>bills;
    int bill;
    int bill_tot(){
        int sum = 

    1*bills[0]+2*bills[1]+5*bills[2]+10*bills[3]+20*bills[4]+50*bills[5]+100*bills[6];
            return sum;
        }
    int main()
    try{
        cout << "Enter the number of One Dollar Bills you have: ";
        cin >> bill;
        cout << '\n';
        bills.push_back(bill);
        if (bill<0)
            error("You can't have a negative value.\n");

        cout << "Enter the number of Two Dollar Bills you have: ";
        cin >> bill;
        cout << '\n';
        bills.push_back(bill);
        if (bill<0)
            error("You can't have a negative value.\n");

        cout << "Enter the number of Five Dollar Bills you have: ";
        cin >> bill;
        cout << '\n';
        bills.push_back(bill);
        if (bill<0)
            error("You can't have a negative value.\n");

        cout << "Enter the number of Ten Dollar Bills you have: ";
        cin >> bill;
        cout << '\n';
        bills.push_back(bill);
        if (bill<0)
            error("You can't have a negative value.\n");

        cout << "Enter the number of Twenty Dollar Bills you have: ";
        cin >> bill;
        cout << '\n';
        bills.push_back(bill);
        if (bill<0)
            error("You can't have a negative value.\n");

        cout << "Enter the number of Fifty Dollar Bills you have: ";
        cin >> bill;
        cout << '\n';
        bills.push_back(bill);
        if (bill<0)
            error("You can't have a negative value.\n");

        cout << "Enter the number of One Hundred Dollar Bills you have: ";
        cin >> bill;
        cout << '\n';
        bills.push_back(bill);
        if (bill<0)
            error("You can't have a negative value.\n");


        cout << "You have " << bills[0] <<" One Dollar Bills.\n";
        cout << "You have " << bills[1] <<" Two Dollar Bills.\n";
        cout << "You have " << bills[2] <<" Five Dollar Bills.\n";
        cout << "You have " << bills[3] <<" Ten Dollar Bills.\n";
        cout << "You have " << bills[4] <<" Twenty Dollar Bills.\n";
        cout << "You have " << bills[5] <<" Fifty Dollar Bills.\n";
        cout << "You have " << bills[6] <<" One Hundred Dollar Bills.\n";
        cout << "The value of all your Dollar Bills are $" << bill_tot() << endl;
        keep_window_open();
    }
    catch (runtime_error e) {   
        cout << e.what() << '\n';
        keep_window_open();
}
```

Comment: Note that VC++ 2012 does _not_ support initializer lists, but it does support ranged-based for statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is illustrative code:

```
std::vector<int> denomination { 1,2,5,20,50,100}; // Initializer list for vector
int sum = 0;
int number;
for ( int bill : denomination ) // range-based for loop
{
    cout << "Enter the number of $" << bill << " you have: ";
    cin >> number;
    sum += number * bill;
}
```

Comment: Also, @user1715779: While testing whatever program you write, when it asks you how many bills you have try typing "none", hitting enter, and seeing what happens...